# Migrating to datastage v11.3 from v9.1

Tags: migration, datastage

Any challenges faced during/after migrating to datastage v11.3 from v9.1 or any other version

Answer (score 0):

Not many;

Two differences we found is that the port numbers all switch to the secure versions (9445 instead of 9080 as an example)

And if you're using the XML stage, from within Internet Explorer you need to enable a couple of additional ActiveX functions (IE>Tools>Internet Options>Security) and ensure that you enable "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer" (IE>Tools>Internet Options>Advanced) otherwise the XML Stage will throw an error 22

Apologies for the late reply